Are there different types of isomaltulose?
I came across isomaltulose as a sugar alternative with a lower glycolytic index. I understood that palatinose is kind of the brand name for isomaltulose.
Question: If one buys a product where the seller does not mention palatinose, is that a different kind of isomaltulose which has an effect on the ingredients or taste?
(See below two different examples, one mentioning palatinose and one does not)
isomaltulose-palatinose
isomaltulose
